# При попытке подключить БД к питон возникает ошибка, как решить?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
db = Database('C:\dis\Test\database.db')
@dp.message_handler(commands = 'start')
async def start(message: types.message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    buttons = ['С чего мне начать?', 'Лучшие курсы(бесплатные)', 'Лучшие курсы(Платные)', 'Идеи и предложения', 'Совет дня', "Пожертвование в проект"]#, 'Пожертвование в наш проект :)' 
    keyboard.add(*buttons)
    if(not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        db.add_userd(message.from_user.id)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Привет {message.from_user.first_name} очень рад, что ты решил изменить свою жизнь к лучшему', reply_markup=keyboard)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Мы рады, что ты вернулся :)', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

На строчке с условием возникает ошибка:'Database' object has no attribute 'user_exists'
Таблица уже создана и запросы прописаны.Читал, что это может быть из-за относительного пути, но путь к БД указываю полны.

```
    def users_exist(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id, )).fetchall()
            print(result)
            return bool(len(result))
```

Функция, которую я прописал в db.py

[image: Таблица, которую я создал.]

Та же таблица открывается, если запускать запускать Database.db в папки с проектом.

Comment: user_exists и users_exist это сильно разные вещи

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли найти опечатку)
Вот только сейчас, уже ошибка в том, что не видит таблицу users

Comment: Ну вопрос по сути тот же - а почему вы решили, что она должна быть видна? "Таблица уже создана" - где и как?

Comment: Я создал ее в SQLlite studio и файл с таблицей сохранил в одной папке с Python файлом

Comment: Именно по пути `C:\dis\Test\database.db`? Открывали-проверяли, что таблица никуда не исчезла?

Comment: Да, и сейчас перепроверил, открываю, а там нужная таблица.

Comment: Покажите скриншот, например?

Comment: Ладно, какая конкретно ошибка-то?

Comment: no such table: users
На 3 строке в файле с обращением к БД
result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id, )).fetchall()